# Pronunciation of Fermat in Gascon/Occitan

Tags: pronunciation, history, proper-nouns, catalan, occitan

A math professor mentioned that the final segment of Fermat's name would probably have been pronounced [t] because of "where he was from." She didn't clarify further but I looked up where he's from and he was Gascon and a speaker of that language (sometimes considered a dialect of Occitan). Could someone confirm that this would have been the case in the Occitan of his day? I searched around and couldn't find anything attesting to this.

Comment: It looks like your professor is correct. Wiki mentions  petit/pichòt [peˈtit]/[piˈtʃɔt] https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gascon_language

Comment: It is hard to answer to this question because it is a proper name. As for the pronunciation of 't', in a general way, it does not seem that the Gascon pronounces systematically this sound at the end of words. There is also a lot of variation inside of Gascon. Look at this website, there are some spoken corpora on the Romance varieties of France: https://atlas.limsi.fr/index-en.html

Comment: Do you mean "how might he have pronounced it if he spoke the local dialect?", or "how did he himself actually pronounce it?". Recall that he was rather upper class.

Comment: @user6726 either question. Was the pronunciation of the final /t/ stigmatized in his day?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fermat was fluent in multiple languages, including French and Occitan. Though he was born and raised in Beaumont-de-Lomagne (Occitania), his paternal family was originally from Catalonia:

> In the second half of the fifteenth century, the Fermat family apparently emigrated from Catalonia to Beaumont-de-Lomagne...
>
> - [*Pierre de Fermat (1601?-1665): His life besides mathematics*](https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence/when-was-pierre-de-fermat-born), European Mathematical Society Newsletter (No.42)

As such his name's authentic pronunciation was likely `/ferˈmat/`.

A contemporary prestige dialect French pronunciation would likely have been `/fer'ma(t)/`, since texts from the late 17th century imply that word terminal *-t* should only regularly be pronounced when occurring before a vowel.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1. [*L'art de prononcer parfaitement la langue françoise*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=VpQPAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA342#v=onepage&q&f=false), 1689 (p.349)</sup>